# Terraform Provider Issue

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I'm trying to upgrade my Terraform state from v0.13.5 to v0.14.0 - I'm gradually updating my Terraform codebase to the latest.

This is what I have in my providers:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.31.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id[var.account_name]}:role/AccessRole"
  }
}
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
  alias  = "prod"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id["prod-account"]}:role/AccessRole"
  }
}
```

This is my main.tf:

```
   data "aws_route53_zone" "r53_zone" {
  provider = aws.prod

  name = var.r53_zone
}

# Create a public DNS zone for VPC
resource "aws_route53_zone" "environment" {
  count = local.is_production_environment ? 0 : 1

  name    = local.base_url
  comment = "'${var.environment}' public zone"

  force_destroy = var.destructable_environment

  tags = merge(local.tags, map("Name", "${var.region}_${var.environment}_public"))
}

# Add record to setup the public zone
resource "aws_route53_record" "environment" {
  count = local.is_production_environment ? 0 : 1

  name     = local.base_url
  zone_id  = data.aws_route53_zone.r53_zone.zone_id
  type     = "NS"
  records  = aws_route53_zone.environment[0].name_servers
  ttl      = 600
  provider = aws.prod
}

resource "aws_shield_protection" "environment_zone" {
  count        = local.is_production_environment ? 0 : 1
  name         = "${var.environment}_environment-zone"
  resource_arn = "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/${aws_route53_zone.environment[0].id}"
}
```

The is the error that I get when running an Terraform Init:

```
Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Error: Invalid legacy provider address

This configuration or its associated state refers to the unqualified provider
"aws".

You must complete the Terraform 0.13 upgrade process before upgrading to later
versions.
```

I'm a bit lost because my current state file is using 0.13.5, and it's telling me to run terraform 0.13upgrade. I've got similar set up in another stack and that upgrade with no issues.

Comment: Are you sure it's not 0.12.x? Also, I think you need to run one [successful apply](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.1.x/upgrade-guides/0-14#:~:text=You%20will%20need%20to%20successfully%20complete%20a%20terraform%20apply%20at%20least%20once%20under%20Terraform%20v0.13%20before%20upgrading%20an%20existing%20configuration%20to%20Terraform%20v0.14.) under 0.13.x to be able to move to 0.14.x.

Comment: The state says the terraform_version is 0.13.5, that's why I'm a bit confused on why it won't update to 0.14.x.

Comment: Ok, my comment still stands for updating to 0.14.x. You need a successful apply first.

Comment: I've just ran a successful apply running on v0.13.5. I've just tried running an apply on v0.14.0 and I get the same error. Unsure what I need to do next.

Comment: Wait, did you run `terraform 0.13upgrade` if you were on 0.12.x?